# Is there any difference between initializing with empty values or null value?

Tags: flutter, null, initialization

Is there any difference between these two part of code? (I am specially using `Flutter/Dart` but also interested to know about this in any other popular languages like C/C++, Java, JS, Python, etc.)

Code1:

```
String a = null; (in Flutter: a = null as String; )
List<T> = null; (in Flutter: List<T> = null as List<T>;)
```

Code 2:

```
String a = '';
List<T> = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

With Dart nullsafety your first examples are invalid (assuming you meant to have a variable name on your List). If a variable can contain null the type needs a '?' suffix:

```
String? a = null;
List<T>? b = null;
```

But with or without nullsafety or '?', use of the variables in your second example won't result in runtime errors. For example `a.trim()`: if a is null a runtime error will occur because you're trying to call `(null).trim()`. In your second example no error because there is a String object to access, even though that String object is empty of characters.  Same for your List: `b.forEach((e) {})` when b==null a runtime error occurs because there's no Object to find forEach() - i.e. the runtime doesn't know what to do with (null).forEach(). In your second example the forEach() doesn't execute the function because List b is empty, but there's no runtime error because there's an Object to call forEach() on.

---

In C: NULL for pointers is usually synonymous with 0. The result of trying to access memory address NULL is "undefined" in C, because it could be valid as 0x00 in some instances like embedded systems or low-level system code, but will usually result in your process being terminated (crash).

Comment: So you say always using the second code is the better option and also we must avoid using the first code at all?

Comment: @ensan3kamel Null is useful for symbolizing something that is missing as opposed to something that is intentionally empty. Imagine you have a file and you want to load that file's contents as a String. The String the file contains can be "" (empty). `String? myFileContents = getMyFileAsString()` might return `null` if the file doesn't exist, where-as returning "" (empty string) would mean the file exists and contains an empty string.  In the case of null, the software might create the missing file and fill it with a default value.